# What is the kinetic energy of a hollow sphere rolling down an incline while slipping?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, friction

A hollow sphere is released from rest from the top of an incline with angle $\theta$ and rolls down while slipping. The coefficient of kinetic friction between incline and sphere is $\mu_k=\frac15\tan\theta$.

After the ball has moved a length $\ell$ down the incline, if we calculate kinetic energy of the ball by finding values of $v$ and $\omega$, we get
$$\text{KE}=\frac12mv^2+\frac12I\omega^2
=\frac{7}{8}mg\ell\sin\theta\tag1$$

According to Work-Energy Theorem, the change in kinetic energy is equal to work done. Thus we also get
$$\text{KE}=mg\ell\sin\theta-\mu_kmg\ell\cos\theta
=\frac12mv^2+\frac12I\omega^2=\frac45mg\ell\sin\theta\tag2$$

I know that Equation (1) is the correct answer **but why are we getting the wrong answer using the Work-Energy Theorem?**

Comment: The problem is in the work of the friction force. The point of contact does not "travel" the same distance as the center of mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only computed that
$$\frac12mv^2=mg\ell(\sin\theta-\mu_k\cos\theta)=\frac45mg\ell\sin\theta$$
You need to compute the angular kinetic energy
$$\frac12I\omega^2=\frac3{40}mg\ell\sin\theta$$
so that
$$\frac12mv^2+\frac12I\omega^2
=\left(\frac45+\frac3{40}\right)mg\ell\sin\theta
=\frac78mg\ell\sin\theta$$
as is required.

Your mistake is in considering only the forces. You have missed out that there will be torque contribution to rotational kinetic energy. i.e. there is a rotational version of Work-Energy Theorem, and this time, you do not know the angle rotated, so that it is difficult to use rWET. You are, of course, allowed to find the angle rotated, and apply rWET, and see that you get the same contribution of $\frac3{40}$, as is needed to be correct.